# Looping through objects and adding types

Tags: javascript

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length ; i++)
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  return list;

}

console.log(arrayToList([10,20]));
```

Why is it that when I `console.log` this array I am obtaining `value : 20`, `rest: object`, and not `value:10`, and `rest: null`. This is confusing me since the first element of my array passed in is 10. and I am going from `i = 0`. Any insight would help. thanks.

Comment: You're modifying the `list` on every iteration, so it makes sense that `value` will be equal to the last item in the `array`.

Comment: Your `for` loop runs over every element in the array (arrays start from index 0).  The 1st time the loop runs, `value` is 10 and `rest` is null.  The ***2nd*** time the loop runs, `value` gets set to 20 then `rest` is set to the previous object.

Comment: As a side question , how can I create a function that would make this arrayToList function back into an array? The solution is here eloquentjavascript.net/code/#4.3, however I am not really sure how to make sense of the for loop I did not know a variable can be the second parameter of a for loop. Any insight please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're returning the last object to have been set to `list`. To return the first in the linked list, retain a reference to it before the loop, and return that.

Though your linked list is going in reverse of the Array. Not sure if that's what you intended.

If you wanted to list to mirror the Array, and link forward, do this:

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  var first = {value: array[0], rest: null};
  var prev = first;
  for (var i = 1; i < array.length ; i++)
    prev.rest = prev = {value: array[i], rest: null};

  return first;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10,20]));
```

---

Let's pretend we don't have a loop, and are just inlining the whole thing. This is how it would look. I'm going to also do it as though the array was `[10, 20, 30]`.

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  // Here `first` and `prev` reference the same object
  var first = {value: array[0], rest: null};
  var prev = first;

  // first = {value: 10, rest: null};
  // prev = {value: 10, rest: null};

  // Then we assign a new object to `prev.rest` as well as `prev`.
  // Because the `prev` and `first` variables reference the same object,
  // the mutation of `prev.rest` is also seen from `first.rest`.

  // First iteration
  prev.rest = prev = {value: array[1], rest: null};

  // now...
  // first = {value: 10, rest: (reference to object with value: 20)};
  // prev = {value: 20, rest: null};

  // So it first changed `prev.rest` (and therefore `first.rest`) to point to
  // the new object, but then it also updated `prev` to the same, new object.

  // Take note that though we assigned the new object to `prev.rest`, after
  // the assignment, `prev.rest` is actually `null`, because the `prev.rest`
  // that we assigned to was the `.rest` of the *previous* `prev`, which was
  // immediately updated to see the *new* object.

  // Second iteration
  prev.rest = prev = {value: array[2], rest: null};

  // now...
  // first = {value: 10, rest: (reference to object with value: 20)};
  // prev = {value: 30, rest: null};

  // So now when we changed `prev.rest`, it had no impact on `first` because
  // `prev` and `first` are referencing different objects. So `prev` sees the
  // new object, but `first` does not.

  return first;
}
```

Comment: If backward references are OK, then your current code would be fine, since returning the first object would have no way to get to the rest.

Comment: This had no actual purpose , it was more of just a test of how to loop through types and such

Comment: As a side question , how can I create a function that would make this arrayToList function back into an array? The solution is here http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#4.3, however I am not really sure how to make sense of the for loop I did not know a variable can be the second parameter of a for loop. Any insight please?

Comment: @cresjoy: In a `for` loop, any value can be the condition. This is because all values in JS have a "truthy" or "falsey" value. If you have an object, it will be "truthy", where as `null` is "falsey", so the loop will continue until it gets `null` as the condition. `for (var obj=list, arr=[]; obj; obj=obj.rest) { arr.push(obj.value) }`

Comment: I think I am still confused. If you change prev in your for loop, how does first obtain the new iterations through the array? you are saying prev = first. not first = prev. Wont first, always just be array[0] and of type null?

Comment: `first` will always be `array[0]` but `first.rest` will not be `null` after the first iteration, because we changed its `.rest` property to the next object, which has `array[1]` and `null`. So `{value: 10, rest: null}` becomes `{value: 10, rest: (the next object)}`, where *(the next object)* is `{value: 20: rest: null}`. The *last* object always has `null`.

Comment: but you changed prev.ref, does this mean that if you have two objects equal to each other, a change to one is a change to another? I mean because usually if you have a variable a, and another variable b, a=b, does not mean b= a, like if you console.log(b), you can get undefined still

Comment: I mean, why even use the variable prev at all?, why not just do first = first.rest etc

Comment: As to `prev.rest`, it's not that they're "equal" to each other, per se. It's that they are a reference to the same object. So you could say they have an equal reference I guess, but yes, a change from one reference changes the other. So since on the first iteration, `prev` and `first` are referencing the same object, so the assignment to `prev.rest` can be "seen" from the `first` reference. After the first iteration, `prev` is now referring to the new object you created, so `prev` and `first` are no longer referencing the same object.

Comment: If we do `first = first.rest`, then we lose hold of the first object that we created, which we want to return. We would always be returning the last object that `first.prev` referenced.

Comment: Thats a beautiful explanatin. I did not notice thats how referencing works. If thats the case why do we need to say prev.rest = prev?, I mean shouldn't prev.rest keep adding onto the previous rest type?

Comment: That's only half the expression. It's not just doing `prev.rest = prev`, but it's doing `prev.rest = prev = {...new object...}`. So both `prev.rest` and `prev` get assigned the new object being created. It's a little tricky, because you need to remember that `prev.rest` is referring to the *old* version of `prev` that existed before `prev` gets the new object. To write it on 2 lines, you'd do `prev.rest = {...new object...};  prev = prev.rest;`

Comment: But doesent say prev.rest = {new object}, add the object onto the rest that  was null before? Why do I need to set prev.rest back to the original prev, I mean should it not keep stacking every iteration since I am adding the new object to the rest type?

Comment: You're not setting `prev.rest` back to the original `prev`. You're setting both `prev` and `prev.rest` to the new object. The chained assignment makes it look a little bit like that, but add parens, and it becomes clearer. `(prev.rest = (prev = {value: array[i], rest: null}));`. This is what lets it keep stacking.

Comment: Ok so on the first iteration prev = value: 20, rest:null, then we say prev.rest becomes value:20, rest:null, after this since prev references the first object, then first.rest becomes the original value appended with this new value. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think so... I mean I'm not quite understanding what you mean, but the `first` variable is only affected during the very first iteration, because when you mutate `prev`, you're mutating `first` as well. But during that first iteration, we update `prev` to point to a new object, so any iterations thereafter will have no impact on the object held by the `first` variable. This is why we need `prev`, so that we can keep adding the new object in each iteration to the previous one without affecting the `first` one.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHH. So are you saying if we simply did prev.rest = {object}, we would be mutating the first rest only, not each successive object, since it will not reference those?

Comment: Yes, if we did only did `prev.rest = {new obj}` in the loop, but never changed `prev`, then we're going to end up with the first object that was created outside the loop pointing to the last object created in the last iteration because we're always mutating the *same* object. I added some explanation to the answer, though I don't know if it makes it much clearer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the value of rest with each of your traversal. I think you should use concept of recursive function to make it fast and accurate.

Please use the following code:

```
function arrayToList(array, i){
    if(i == array.length){
        return null ;
    }
    return { value: array[i], rest: arrayToList(array, i+1) };
}
console.log(arrayToList([10,20,30], 0));
```

Here, `i` represents the index in array. I hope this solves your problem. It worked fine at my system.

The result I got is:

```
{
    value: 10, 
    rest: {
        value: 20, 
        rest: {
            value: 30, 
            rest:null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice recursive solution. I'd be inclined to ditch the `i` and just do `return { value: array.shift(), rest: arrayToList(array) };`, to get the `HEAD|TAIL` behavior *(and change the escape condition of course)*.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a console.log() of the returned "list" value. You will not see a "null" in your list.rest because your final value of list would look like this : 

    `list = {
        value: 20,
        rest : {
            value : 10,
            rest : null
        }
    };`

If you put the following after list = {value: array[i], rest: list}; you will see what I mean : 
console.log(list.rest)
or
console.log(list) if you want to see the whole thing.

Also, to answer you question about starting with your first element being 10 and starting at i=0 : 
the array [10, 20] has an array.length = 2
array[0] = 10
array[1] = 20

Because of this, the last value entered into your "list" will be value = 20. When you do this, you are also storing the value of "list" in "list.rest", which will recursively store whatever your last "list" JSON object was. This could get really messy if you have more than 2 items in the list because with 3, to get to the first, you would have to do list.rest.rest.value -- You probably want to re-think how you're storing your list.