# Looping through types in an object

Tags: javascript

Ok so yesterday I asked a question, and I was able to solve this problem, but after retrying it today I can't really understand why what I did on my own isn't working. My question is basically, why when I log this, is it skipping the first element of my array ( the 20 value). My guess is that the 30 is overwriting the previous spot, but I can't really make sense of **why**. Here is my though on things

First our list is `value:10, rest:null` now i =1, so we will add a value of 20 and another `rest:null` to the pre-existing `rest`. thus get `value:10, rest: value:20, rest:null`, and then the same for the value of 30.

```
function arrayToList(array)
{
    var list = {value : array[0], rest: null } ;
    for ( i =  1 ; i<array.length ; i++)
        {
           list.rest = { value: array[i], rest:null} 

        }
    return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10,20,30]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the value of rest with each of your traversal. I think you should use concept of recursive function to make it fast and accurate.

Please use the following code:

```
function arrayToList(array, i){
    if(i == array.length){
        return null ;
    }
    return { value: array[i], rest: arrayToList(array, i+1) };
}
console.log(arrayToList([10,20,30], 0));
```

Here, `i` represents the index in array. I hope this solves your problem. It worked fine at my system.

The result I got is:

```
{
    value: 10, 
    rest: {
        value: 20, 
        rest: {
            value: 30, 
            rest:null
        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck!!!!

Comment: Beauty. Could you explain what this code does as well? Its an alternative solution with the same answer. I just dont understand what the purpose of using "prev" is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884651/looping-through-objects-and-adding-types/37884688?noredirect=1#comment63228444_37884688

Comment: `prev` helps you in keeping the track of your `rest` key in the list. It will allow you to insert your new values to the `rest` of previously inserted value.

Comment: my code does the same with less amount of memory and time.

Comment: If it helped, could you please accept it as an answer? That'll be great. Thanks!

Comment: It did indeed help, and I will accept it. however do you know of any way of doing this with just using one function parameter which is an array? That would be interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to add remaining values to `rest`. If so you should declare it as an array instead of `null`

```
function arrayToList(array) {
    var list = { value: array[0], rest: [] };
    for(i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        list.rest.push({ value: array[i], rest: null });
    }
    return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]));
```

The above code will return this object

```
{
  value: 10,
  rest: [
    { value: 20, rest: null },
    { value: 30, rest: null }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Almost what I want. I want the second rest ( with value 20), to next again with value : 30, and rest: null

Answer (score 0):

because you start with i=1, it should be i=0.
Arrays are 0-based in JavaScript (and basically every other language).

Comment: That doesen't solve the problem at all or make sense. My first element in list was already predefined at 0. If I start the for loop at zero every iteration will just be a value:10

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is that the 30 is overwriting the previous spot

that's right. You are overwriting `list.rest` property on each loop iteration. So, in the end the `value` property will be filled with the last array value `30`

Comment: show me the full expected result (resulting object). Show how it should look for those three input values

Comment: for example an array input of 10,20,30 should result in value:10, rest: value:20, rest : value : 30, rest:null

Comment: basically keep going down the array until you get to the last spot where rest becomes null

Comment: you can't have same property names in object. One of the valid form would be: `{value:10}, {rest: {value:20}}, {rest : {value : 30, rest:null}}`

Comment: see the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884651/looping-through-objects-and-adding-types/37884688?noredirect=1#comment63228444_37884688

Comment: I'm just not sure the reason for the prev variable

Comment: I guess, you want a nested objects in `rest` property, right?

Comment: @cresjoy, looks like @ BABU's solution should resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution is recommended :

```
function arrayToList(array, i){
    if(!i){i=0;}
    if(i == array.length){
        return null ;
    }
    return { value: array[i], rest: arrayToList(array, i+1) };
}
```

Then :

```
console.log(arrayToList([10,20,30]));
```

Comment: Not the same solution . Check again

Comment: the main idea(recursive function) is identical, the rest trifles are negligible